# Can we handle the dynamic pop up? If yes, Then how we can get the dynamic elements count at run time?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code for find out the total elements present in the popup and when I execute the code, every time it return total number of elements is equal to 1. But actually more than 1 elements is present in the popup.

- Can anyone tell me that how I can get the exact number of elements from the pop up?
- Can we handle the dynamic pop up? If yes, Then how we can get the dynamic elements count at run time?

For Example:

In a pop up there is total four elements present (two checkboxes and two text fields). And suppose Admin has deleted two fields from the backend, now total two fields are present in the frontend. But I have already written the code for four fields, so if run the code, it will obviously display an error message in the console i.e `NoSuchElementFound`.

[image]

So my question How we can handle this situation? Please help.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.GetAttribute;


public class dynamicform {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public void Dynamicform() throws InterruptedException {

        //Launch Google Chrome Browser                
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(" "); // Redirect to the Website(put any website link)
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater2_btnSPrequest_1")).click(); //Click on the popup button
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Control6-0_txtquestion")).sendKeys("asdasd");//sending text to any particular text field

        //Listing all the popup forms elements 
        List<WebElement> forms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".modal-popup"));

        //print the Total pop up Elements
        int count = forms.size();
        System.out.println("Total No. of Elements Present" + count);

        //Run the advance for loop
        for (WebElement ele : forms) {
            //Print the pop up elements "id"
            System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("id"));

            //Print the pop up elements text
            System.out.println(ele.getText());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Creating the object of the class
        dynamicform obj3 = new dynamicform();

        // call the Dynamicform method
        obj3.Dynamicform();

        // Closing the Driver
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you switching to the pop-up from the main window before you run the rest of the code?

Comment: If admins has deleted two fields, you can't interact with those elements and there will be NoSuchElementFound error as you says. And it should be! Let's clarify that you're testing a webpage, right? If someone deletes some fields, it means that you're test needs to be modified if your test needs those elements (seems it is)

Comment: I think its not like a new Window. Its a modal  pop-up extender of Ajax tool kit,which appears on the same screen &  user controls are loading dynamically and without switching into the pop up  I can able to sendKeys for the text fields of the popup. But I am not getting the Total Elements present in the pop up.(i.e how many text fields, radio button and check-boxes are present into the pop up screen ), If I count the elements, it always returned Total no. of Elements =1 since the controls are loading dynamically so these controls are not getting rendered.       @Grasshopper & Taylan

Comment: @Arijit This statement - List<WebElement> forms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".modal-popup")); Are you sure that all the elements use this class? Or is this the class of the popup? Can you share the page source of the popup?

Comment: Here is the page source , I have Uploaded in google drive. Please check. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzPeknVPB8NvQW0yVlpweGktRWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Arijit Try this css instead of ".modal-popup" -- "span[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_Control0-'][class*='col-lg-11']". This should give you the span with the text. Well hopefully...

Comment: @Grasshopper:Thanks for your support.Its almost working but one small things that  when I am using this css "span[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_Control0-'][class*='col-lg-11‌​']" its returns Total Element =0 and When using only span[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_Control0-'] this time its shows Total Elements = 12 including "RequiredFieldValidator" elements. I just want the input tags elements not "RequiredFieldValidator" elements. so could you please suggest what should be the cssSelector for that?

Comment: div[class='form-group'] > span[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_Control0-']

Comment: @Grasshopper: Simply Awesome.Thank you so so much Sir for your help.